# Expected time until k failures among n items each independent and having exponential distribution

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, expected-value, exponential-distribution, gamma-distribution

This is the question I am trying to solve. "Suppose that n items are being tested simultaneously, the items are independent, and the length of life of each item has the exponential distribution with parameter β. Determine the expected length of time until three items have failed"

I approached the problem like this. Since the sampled items are independent, and we are looking for time until the third failure, we can model this as gamma distribution with parameter alpha = 3 and beta = beta. Hence the Expected value is 3 / β.

But when I checked the solution, the correct answer is

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KG4nq.png)

Could you kindly explain why it cant be considered as gamma distribution but instead we need to find the expectation of sum of time until successive failures.

The problem is in [Probablity and Statistics 4th ed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321500466) Problem 11 on sec 5.7. Page 325

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gamma distribution with parameters $\ 3,\beta\ $ is the distribution of the *sum* of three $\ \beta$-exponentially distributed independent random variables, so its mean is the expected value of time taken to test three items to failure *sequentially*.  But this isn't the problem you're trying to solve, in which there are $\ n\ $ items being tested *simultaneously*. This means that when the *first* failure occurs, all the other tests are still running, so the times when any of the items in those other tests fail *can't* be earlier than the time when the first failure occurred.

Thus, if $\ f_1\ $ is the index of the item which fails first, then
$$
X_{f_1}\le X_i\ \ \text{ for all }\ \ i\ ,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
X_{f_1}=\min\big(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\big)\ .
$$

Now if $\ X_{f_1}=\min\big(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n\big)\ $, then $\ X_{f_1}>x\ $ if and only if $\ X_i>x\ $ for all $\ i=1,2,\dots,n\ $.  Therefore,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_1}>x\big)&=\mathbb{P}\big(X_1>x, X_2>x,\dots,X_n>x\big)\\
&=\prod_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}\big(X_i>x\big)\\
&=e^{-n\beta x}\ ,
\end{align}
and the cumulative distribution function of $\ X_{f_1}\ $ is given by
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_1}\le x\big)&=1-\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_1}>x\big)\\
&=1-e^{-n\beta x}\ .
\end{align}
Thus, $\ X_{f_1}\ $ is $\ n\beta$-exponentially distributed and therefore has mean $\ \frac{1}{n\beta}\ $.

Likewise, if $\ f_2\ $ and $\ f_3\ $ are the indices of the second and third items to fail, then $\ X_{f_1}\le X_{f_2}\le X_{f_3}\le X_i\ $ for all $\ i\not\in\big\{f_1,f_2\big\}\ $, and the expected time until the third failure (which is the quantity you're asked to find) is $\ \mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_3}\big)\ $.

By a derivation similar to that of the distribution of $\ X_{f_1}\ $, we get the conditional cumulative distribution of $\ X_{f_2}\ $ given $\ X_{f_1}\ $ to be given by
$$
\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_2}\le x\,\big|\, X_{f_1}=z\big)=1-e^{-(n-1)\beta(x-z)}\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_2}-X_{f_1}\le x\,\big|\, X_{f_1}=z\big)&=\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_2}-z\le x\,\big|\, X_{f_1}=z\big)\\
&=\mathbb{P}\big(X_{f_2}\le x+z\,\big|\, X_{f_1}=z\big)\\
&=1-e^{-(n-1)\beta x}\ .
\end{align}
That is, the conditional distribution of $\ X_{f_2}-X_{f_1}\ $ given $\ X_{f_1}\ $ is exponential with parameter $\ (n-1)\beta\ $, so its conditional expectation given $\ X_{f_1}\ $ is
$$
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_2}-X_{f_1}\,\big|\, X_{f_1}=z\big)=\frac{1}{(n-1)\beta}\ ,
$$
and integrating this with respect to the distribution of $\ X_{f_1}\ $ gives
$$
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_2}-X_{f_1}\big)=\frac{1}{(n-1)\beta}\ .
$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_2}\big)&=\mathbb{E}\left(\big(X_{f_2}-X_{f_1}\big)+X_{f_1}\right)\\
&=\frac{1}{(n-1)\beta}+\frac{1}{n\beta}\ .
\end{align}

Essentially the same argument will give
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_3}-X_{f_2}\,\big|\, X_{f_2}=z\big)&=\frac{1}{(n-2)\beta}\ ,\\
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_3}-X_{f_2}\big)&=\frac{1}{(n-2)\beta}\ ,\text{ and}\\
\mathbb{E}\big(X_{f_3}\big)&=\frac{1}{(n-2)\beta}+\frac{1}{(n-1)\beta}+\frac{1}{n\beta}\ .
\end{align}

Comment: Cool. Thanks So to summarize, expectation gamma distribution is E(X1 + X2 + ... ) where as in this question we are trying to find E(X1 + X2 + ... + Xn = 3) ? i.e. Gamma distribution is used when we dont have any constraint on the sum of exponentially distributed random variables. I.e. = f(x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + xn) where f is pdf of beta distribution. where as here we are trying to find expectation of f(x1 + x2 + ... + xn = 3) ?

Comment: The expectation of the gamma distribution with parameters $\ 3,\beta\ $ is $\ E(X_1+X_2+X_3)\ $, but for this question, the expectation is $\ E(X_{i_3})\ $, where $\ i_3\ $ is the index of the *third smallest* of $\ X_1, X_2,\dots, X_n\ $.   It looks like my answer needs further clarification, which I will add later today.

Answer (score 0):

Let's revisit a simplified question first, what is the expected value of the minimum of $n$ independent exponential distributions with parameter $\beta$, it is not $\frac1{\beta}$, rather it is $\frac1{n\beta}$.

For the context of your question, we have to find the expected time of the minimum of the $n$ exponential distributions, followed by the expected time of the minimum of the  remaining $n-1$ exponential distributions, and the expected time of the minimum of the remaining $n-2$ exponential distributions.

Comment: Thanks. I get that. But my question was why we need to do it by computing the minimum ? What is difference btw this question and gamma distribution. Anyways, I got some idea from "lonza leggiera". Pls feel free to add. Thanks again.